# json_encode an array posted from a form

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, wordpress

I have an array being passed to a method to insert into a database.

I've tried:

```
$names = $_POST['names'];

json_encode($names);
echo '<pre>' .print_r($names,1). '</pre>';
exit;
```

And...

```
json_encode($names = $_POST['names']);
```

But neither seem to work.. Note that when i am debugging to print the json encoded array, it is just showing the array and its values - no json :(
which suggests the array is being passed fine but the json encoding is not working!

cheers

Comment: Are you getting values within `$_POST['names'];` and you can simply use `echo` instead of `print_r`

Comment: Yes:   Array
(
    [0] => tom
    [1] => james
)

Comment: Simply use `echo json_encode($_POST['names']);`

Comment: @Uchiha What will it change? :)

Comment: It won't change anything but it seems OP want to echo array in JSON format @splash58

Comment: Do you have anything else within your mind @splash58

Comment: @bri before thinking that json library does not work , please, show results of `var_dump ($names);` before and echo `json_encode($names);` after encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the returned string.
`json_encode` does not modify your array, arguments are [passed by value](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

```
$names = $_POST['names'];

$jsonEncoded = json_encode($names);
echo $jsonEncoded;
```